# I'm getting ssh attacks

Tags: ssh, nginx

I'm getting millions requests in short time like in picture.

[Vestacp Mysql Request Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZccPt.jpg)

When this attacks happend if i login ssh it shows this message.

> Last failed login: Wed Dec 16 12:52:56 EET 2015 from 43.229.53.24 on
>   ssh:notty There were 66 failed login attempts since the last
>   successful login.

So its look like query attack but possible to similiar ssh attack. I dont understand.

My server

- Centos 7.2 x64 Vestacp with Nginx

I have fail2ban and when i try 5 false login its ban to my ip.

But how they try 66 login attempts?

i dont understand.

I'm waiting for help .Sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 3):

Since your last login, 66 attempts have been made that failed. Even you could have been among these attempts, when mistyping the password. Others have tried, and after five attempts they got blocked by Fail2ban, probably for 24 hours - depending on the Fail2ban settings.

It seems that from at least 14 different ip addresses they have attempted to login to your machine, since your last succesful login. 66 / 5 = 13.2, so more than 13 ip addresses were involved, and maximum 66.

When you logged in, this number is reset, and maybe more attempts were made. You can set fail2ban to mail you these reports. Or you can install logwatch to see what's happening.

I don't know what that Mysql report has to do with this. They do not relate.

Comment: I think i find my problem.When i tried to login phpmyadmin im not getting ban.So fail2ban need to protect this area too.